# DateInterval into Integer

Tags: php

I'm trying to multiple a dateInterval to a value, I am getting the error

Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int

How would I convert it into a integer

```
$date1 =  new DateTime($t1);
$date2 =  new DateTime($t2);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->format("%a");

$total = $price * $diff;
```

Comment: `$total = $price * $diff->format("%a");`

Comment: Please read your code again. You already know about the `format()` method!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using the object for calculation. You need to get the days and use that for calculation Use like this:

```
$date1 =  new DateTime($t1);
$date2 =  new DateTime($t2);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
$days = $diff->format("%a");

$total = $price * $days;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$date1 =  new DateTime($t1);
$date2 =  new DateTime($t2);
$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$interval =  $diff->format("%a");

$total = $price * $interval;
```

I have assigned difference to $interval